# App dynamic shortcuts do not appear in assistant [when using an account different of the publishing one]

Tags: android, app-actions, android-shortcut

I have an android app that:

- Does not use shortcuts.
- Does not use app-actions.
- Uses dynamic shortcuts.

The code to register the dynamic shortcut is like this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.putExtra("id", (long)id);

            ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder scBuilder = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(this, "View " + doc.getName())
              .setShortLabel("View " + doc.getName())
              .setLongLabel("View " + doc.getName())
              .addCapabilityBinding("custom.actions.intent.ACTION")
              .setIntent(intent);

            if (!ShortcutManagerCompat.pushDynamicShortcut(this, scBuilder.build()))
            {
                Log.d("INTENT", "onCreate: Failed...");
            }
```

When I use it on a phone that has google assistant logged in on the same account that is used to publish the app, it works fine.
As soon as I log out and use another account, dynamic shortcuts no longer appear in the assistant.
This behaviour is the same with the already published app (as in app publicly available on PlayStore).

To me it furiously looks like some action must be performed to "get my app out of sandbox" so everyone can use the feature.

I'm aware that for apps using app-actions, you need approval from Google. However the app-action team at Google told me since I'm actually not using app-actions, it is not in their power.

---

In my exchange with them app actions team at Google, I told them my app didn't use app-action or shortcuts, they told me the dynamic shortcut team confirmed it's ok to have just dynamic shortcuts, however it's in beta, and if I have issues I should post here. Hence me posting.

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you "log out and use another account"?  Please edit the question to walk through the steps you take that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can no longer get it to work (as in the shortcut to appear in google assistant). The shortcuts are still visible when long-pressing the app icon in the launcher.

Comment: From the top of my head, the "steps" I used to switch account was to remove the Google account from the phone, then add another one, go to voice assistant and enable it again.

Comment: @user1532080 I am having the same issue. Did you find any solution for the same? Can you please guide me here

Comment: @JeetRaval I don't have a proven solution yet. In the meantime, the Android Studio plugins got upgraded and shortchuts got out of beta. So far, I'm testing something that uses shortcuts.xml, still with the code above. And it works. The only difference is having a shortcut.xml

Comment: @user1532080 Can you please guide me that what details should I add in shortcut.xml file and do I need to perform any other step to get a shortcut in google assistant settings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JeetRaval I'm afraid I can't as it depends on your actual needs. You might want to post a question about that. Documentation about shortcut.xml is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/action-schema

Comment: @user1532080 I have already posted a question about the same. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73488272/how-to-add-static-custom-shortcut-word-programmatically-with-the-shortcuts-xml-f

Comment: @JeetRaval Read your question, that's not the same, you're after static shortcuts...